# I can't initialize variable with tensorflow (protobuf error)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I installed `tensorflow 2.2.0` (`protobuf 3.12.2`) on my ubuntu machine (20.04) through pip. I let pip take care of all the dependencies. My problem is I receive an error everytime I try initializing a `Variable`. Below the sample code

```
import tensorflow as tf
 
class LinearModel:
    def __call__(self, x):
        return self.Weight * x + self.Bias

    def __init__(self):
        self.Weight = tf.Variable(11.0)
        self.Bias = tf.Variable(12.0)       
    
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    linear_model = LinearModel()
```

I took it from here

https://morioh.com/p/b12da909d731

The error I receive

```
AttributeError: 'google.protobuf.pyext._message.RepeatedCompositeCo' object has no attribute 'append'
```

(if required I can put the whole trace)

Attempt I've made

1. trying multiple version of protobuf (I've read it could be a version mismatch although I did not find a suitable version)
2. installing nightly builds of tensorflow
3. tried on windows, **it works**

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Debian testing with tensorflow-cpu 2.2.0. Can you tell us more about your environment?

Comment: @Vittorio Apicella, Yes, couldn't reproduce the error. Can you try installing Tensorflow in a Virtual Environment and see how it goes. Thanks!